# How to report a bug of Gdata API of Java

Tags: java, gdata-api

```
service.getListFeed(worksheets.get(i).getListFeedUrl()).getEntries()
```

is returing me empty list as there are records in my work sheet. I know what the problem is, I have done some RnD, all I want to know is, how to report a but to google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this snippet from [Googles developer site for GData](https://developers.google.com/gdata/faq):

> Check out our issue tracker at http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/list. Look for your feature request and star it to add your support and receive updates on its status.